# reproducibleFileOrder not propagated to included projects

Tags: build.gradle

I have a project demo2 that has settings.gradle as follows

```
rootProject.name = 'demo2'
include ":demo"
project(":demo").projectDir = file("../demo")
```

and build.gradle with following section in it

```
tasks.withType(AbstractArchiveTask) {
    preserveFileTimestamps = false
    reproducibleFileOrder = true
}
```

I have another project demo1 that builds demo.jar
My question is - when demo2.jar is being built, it is built correctly with reproducibleFileOrder = true, however when it builds the sub project demo, it does not apply this setting, so sub project is being built incorrectly.

Question is - how can I propagate build.gradle settings to sub project?
(Note that I do not know the subprojects, so I cannot change their build.gradle file)

Alternative can be, is there a way to build subproject by specifying "reproducibleFileOrder = true" on the command line first then building demo2?